# How to add array to JQWidget pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, pie-chart, jqwidget

I am trying to use a [JQWidget](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm#demos/jqxchart/javascript_chart_pie_series_legend.htm) pie chart. The initial example is in a text file, but I would like to use my own values in the chart. I have 4 sections (A,B,C,Unknown) that will add up to 100 to create the pie chart.

Category A has a value of APercent

Category B has a value of BPercent

Category C has a value of CPercent

Category Unknown has a value of UKPercent

I am stuck trying to add all of the values to the pie chart. Currently my chart loads the four legends but without names and loads only one of the categories.

[image]

```
 var bigPie = [];


       bigPie.push({
         A: APercent
        });
       bigPie.push({
         B: BPercent
        });
       bigPie.push({
         C: CPercent
        });
       bigPie.push({
         Unknown: UKPercent
        });





$(document).ready(function () {

 // prepare chart data as an array
          // prepare jqxChart settings
            var settings = {
                title: "Information",
                description: "Legs",
                enableAnimations: true,
                showLegend: true,
                showBorderLine: true,
                legendLayout: { left: 700, top: 160, width: 300, height: 200, flow: 'vertical' },
                padding: { left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 },
                titlePadding: { left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 },
                source: bigPie,

                colorScheme: 'scheme03',
                seriesGroups:
                    [
                        {
                            type: 'pie',
                            showLabels: true,
                            series:
                                [
                                    {
                                        dataField: ‘A',
                                        displayText: ‘%',
                                        labelRadius: 170,
                                        initialAngle: 15,
                                        radius: 145,
                                        centerOffset: 0,
                                        formatFunction: function (value) {
                                            if (isNaN(value))
                                                return value;
                                            return parseFloat(value) + '%';
                                        },
                                    }
                                ]
                        }
                    ]
            };
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance. If I am not clear or too vague about something, then please let me know. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, your array must have objects which has 2 properties at least.
one for the label (A,B,C,D in your case)
and the other for the value (APercent,BPercent,CPercent,UKPercent in your case)
it looks like this..

```
var bigPieTobe = [
    {category:"A", percent: 20}
    , {category:"B", percent: 30}
    , {category:"C", percent: 40}
    , {category:"Unknown", percent: 10}
];
```

second, you must tell jqxChart which property is category and which is value.

```
           dataField: 'percent',
            displayText: 'category',
```

full source code would be like this...

```
// prepare chart data as an array
var bigPieTobe = [
    {category:"A", percent: 20}
    , {category:"B", percent: 30}
    , {category:"C", percent: 40}
    , {category:"Unknown", percent: 10}
];

// prepare jqxChart settings
var settings = {
    title: "Information",
    description: "Legs",
    enableAnimations: true,
    showLegend: true,
    showBorderLine: true,
    legendLayout: { left: 700, top: 160, width: 300, height: 200, flow: 'vertical' },
    padding: { left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 },
    titlePadding: { left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 },
    source: bigPieTobe,

    colorScheme: 'scheme03',
    seriesGroups:
    [
        {
            type: 'pie',
            showLabels: true,
            series:
            [
                {
                    dataField: 'percent',
                    displayText: 'category',
                    labelRadius: 170,
                    initialAngle: 15,
                    radius: 145,
                    centerOffset: 0,
                    formatFunction: function (value) {
                        if (isNaN(value))
                            return value;
                        return parseFloat(value) + '%';
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
$("#jqxChart").jqxChart(settings);
```

you can see the result here http://jsfiddle.net/znwua337/1/